# (Android) How to set colors.xml data using Java programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I want to modify the value of a color in `colors.xml`, such as

`<color name="colorPrimary">#3D3D3D</color>`. I want to change this using Java programatically so I can modify this while the app is running.

I have tried things like `R.color.colorPrimary = "#FFFFFF";` but this throws an incompatable types error because R.color.primary must be set to a int, not a String.

How do I change the colors.xml data using Java?

Comment: This is not possible to change static resource such as `color.xml` at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't change these values while the app is running, instead, make two colors in colors.xml and then you can access them using JAVA `getResources().getColor(R.id.colorPrimary)` or if you want to change the theme colors you can make different themes with different colors and change between them in runtime, more info in [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color a component, you only need to put the next code

```
bbbb.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, int codecolor))
ccc.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, int codeColor))
```

Comment: You have the reason, i didn't understood the question well, but you cant change the values of resources, only you can modify the components or assign new color